# How to use @kotlinx.serialization.Serializable with java.time.Instant?

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization

I'm learning how to use Ktor's HttpClient. And, I'd like it to automatically convert a JSON response into a data class. I think I have all the setup correct (pasted below), but unfortunately, `java.time.Instant` uses `import java.io.Serializable;`, which I guess isn't compatible with kotlinx's `@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable`.

So, how can I get Ktor to recognize `Instant` as serializable?

```
val httpClient = HttpClient(CIO) {
    install(JsonFeature) {
        serializer = KotlinxSerializer(Json {
            prettyPrint = true
            isLenient = true
        })
    }
}
val response: MyResponse = httpClient.get(baseUrl() + "/example/path") {
    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
}

@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
data class MyResponse(
    val name: String,
    val time: Instant // ERROR: "Serializer has not been found for type 'Instant'. To use context serializer as fallback, explicitly annotate type or property with @Contextual"
)
```

Sidenote: Other answers using Gson or Jackson or other serializers could be useful too since they may not have to explicitly add `@Serializable`

Answer (score 11):

Another solution, if you want or need to keep using `java.time` directly, is to create your own serializer for `java.time.Instant`. See the following example. Note Kotlin 1.9.0, Kotlin Serialization 1.5.1, and Gradle 8.2.1 was used for testing.

**InstantSerializer.kt**:

```kotlin
package sample

import kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.PrimitiveKind
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.PrimitiveSerialDescriptor
import kotlinx.serialization.descriptors.SerialDescriptor
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Decoder
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Encoder
import java.time.Instant

object InstantSerializer : KSerializer<Instant> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("java.time.Instant", PrimitiveKind.STRING)
    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: Instant) = encoder.encodeString(value.toString())
    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Instant = Instant.parse(decoder.decodeString())
}
```

<sup>**Note:** Encoding to, and decoding from, the ISO-8601 representation ensures no precision is lost. That's one of the approaches used by the *kotlinx-datetime* library (see [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime/blob/master/core/common/src/serializers/InstantSerializers.kt)). The other approach that library offers is to encode the epoch seconds and nano-of-seconds separately, both as numbers. If you prefer that, look at the library's implementation (linked earlier). Also note that when running on the JVM, the *kotlinx-datetime* classes are backed by the `java.time` classes.</sup>

**Event.kt** (the serializable data class with an `Instant` property):

```kotlin
@file:UseSerializers(InstantSerializer::class)

package sample

import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.UseSerializers
import java.time.Instant

@Serializable
data class Event(val name: String, val instant: Instant)
```

<sup>**Note:** An alternative to using to using `@UseSerializers` would be to annotate the `instant` property with `@Serializable(InstantSerializer::class)`.</sup>

**Main.kt**:

```kotlin
package sample

import kotlinx.serialization.encodeToString
import kotlinx.serialization.json.Json
import java.time.Instant

fun main() {
    val event = Event("Test Event", Instant.now())

    val jsonString = Json.encodeToString(event)
    val decodedEvent = Json.decodeFromString<Event>(jsonString)

    println("Original Event = $event")
    println("JSON String    = $jsonString")
    println("Decoded Event  = $decodedEvent")
}
```

**Example output**:

```
Original Event = Event(name=Test Event, instant=2023-07-11T10:16:34.742769200Z)
JSON String    = {"name":"Test Event","instant":"2023-07-11T10:16:34.742769200Z"}
Decoded Event  = Event(name=Test Event, instant=2023-07-11T10:16:34.742769200Z)
```

---

Here was the Gradle build file used to run the above code (Kotlin DSL):

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.0"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.9.0"
    application
}

application {
    mainClass.set("sample.MainKt")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.5.1")
}
```

And it was executed with:

```
./gradlew run
```

Comment: how would you implement it to avoid that? I'm having the same issue

Comment: Updated answer to provide an example that doesn't result in loss of nanosecond precision.

Comment: I like to declare it like this:


@Serializable
    data class SomeClass(val myVal: @Serializable(with = InstantSerializer::class) Instant)

Answer (score 10):

One solution is to use the kotlinx-datetime library (https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime), which gives you a Kotlin version of Instant with the `@kotlinx.serialization.Serializable` that you are looking for.

So, instead of using `java.time.Instant`, you could use `kotlinx.datetime.Instant` in MyResponse.

> Note that the library is experimental, and the API is subject to change.
> (Source: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime#using-in-your-projects)