# Kotlin: How do I serialize LocalDateTime using kotlinx serializer?

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.serialization

How would I go about serializing `LocalDateTime` using `kotlinx serializer`

I've read that I would need to include `implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-datetime:0.4.0")` in my dependencies, which I did, but I'm still getting this error:

`Serializer has not been found for type 'LocalDateTime'. To use context serializer as fallback, explicitly annotate type or property with @Contextual`

Is there something else I should also imported in the same script?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Importing the `kotlinx-datetime` library is not enough; you have to use the types from that library, instead of `java.time`, as the `kotlinx-datetime` types are annotated with the appropriate `@Serializable` annotations. If you wish to continue using the `java.time` types directly, then you'll need to create your own serializers. See [this related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71629874/6395627). It none of this helps solve your problem then please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own serializer model, using:

Imports:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.serialization.ExperimentalSerializationApi
import kotlinx.serialization.KSerializer
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializer
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Decoder
import kotlinx.serialization.encoding.Encoder
```

```kotlin
@Serializer(forClass = LocalDate::class)
object DateSerializer : KSerializer<LocalDate> {
    private val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: LocalDate) {
        encoder.encodeString(value.format(formatter))
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): LocalDate {
        return LocalDate.parse(decoder.decodeString(), formatter)
    }
}
```

And then use a @Serializabe class describer, for example:

```kotlin
    @Serializable(with = DateSerializer::class)
    val startDate: LocalDate,
    @Serializable(with = DateSerializer::class)
    val endDate: LocalDate
```